# jquery tokeninput uncommon parameters sent, not working anymore in rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-tokeninput, loopj

I know tokeninput isn't made for rails specifically, but after upgrading from 3.2 to 3.2.12 it doesn't work anymore. It doesn't get the results.

All I have as a clue are 2 parameters that weren't sent in the older version of rails: Started GET "/tags.json?callback=jQuery191040979262322760657_1364525075625&q=books&_=1364525075627"

The "callback" and "_" parameter are new to me. They weren't sent in 3.2.

I can't identify the problem. It seems that the request goes through well, but then there's no response coming through back to tokeninput.

I hope somebody might have a clue. The logic in controller and model works fine, tested it in console etc. The only hint I have really are those 2 parameters.

Any help appreciated! I really can't solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this had nothing to do with rails 3.2.13 or so. The problem was tokeninput was making a crossDomain request from within a subdomain towards a path without a subdomain, logically. I should have noticed. All I needed to do was to send the json response together with the callback. Should have done more research on this topic. Sorry